# Azure SQL Server 2014 Express VM: Cannot update/patch SQL Server Express

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, sql-server-2014, windows-update

I created an Azure Resource Manager VM using the standard Azure image "SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express on Windows Server 2012 R2".

I immediately ran Windows Update and all patches for the server worked but the Security Update for SQL Server 2014 Service Pack 1 (KB3070446) failed with a error code of 84B30002.

The Azure VM SQL Express version (`SELECT @@VERSION`) is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4193.9 (X64) Nov 28 2015 03:44:12 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

This version is not a documented SQL Server 2014 Express version (as far as I can see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/321185#bookmark-sqlserver2014)).

I have tried installing CU 5 for SQL Server 2014 Express but that couldn't find a valid version of SQL Server to update.

Do you think it is non-standard version of SQL Server Express that is causing the update to fail? I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a ticket with Microsoft and they confirmed that the SQL Express version number caused the problem.  Their response was:

> the product team has confirmed that the "SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express
>   on Windows Server 2012 R2" image was wrongly built by an internal
>   builds (12.0.4193.9).

I am not sure when they will have it fixed.  As a workaround I uninstalled SQL Express and re-installed from a public download of SQL Express.

Please NOTE: I had to install the SQL Express as a "DEFAULT" instance (MSSQLSERVER).  I tried to install the new SQL Express as a “Named” instance (SQLEXPRESS) instead of the “default” instance (MSSQLSERVER).  This didn’t work for me however.  I found that I couldn’t contact SQL Server from my other VM that was running my application.  So I installed SQL Express as a “default” instance and communication from the other VM started working!

Comment: Microsoft have now fixed the issue.  The product team has confirmed that the new image has been released to the portal now (“SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express on Windows Server 2012 R2”).

Answer (score 1):

“Named” instance (SQLEXPRESS) will use dynamic port
"DEFAULT" instance (MSSQLSERVER) will use 1433 as a default one.
If you want to use “Named” instance (SQLEXPRESS) configure the firewall properly or else Change the dynamic port in SQL server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for that extra info.  Good to know